# $m-isomorphism$ - not understanding this term. Ask for explanation.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

$G_1, G_2$ is graph.   What does it mean that:  $G_1\equiv_m G_2$ ?
And what does it mean that $G_1\equiv G_2$ ?
What about consequnces ?  At this moment I wouldnt like to know underlying and complex theory. I ask only for inuitions and consequences like using $m$-isomorphism to show that there is no first-order sentence about graphs.

When it comes to common isomorphism I get it.  For example two graps (structures) are isomorphic functions and relation in both structures behave in the same way.

Comment: I've never heard of $m$-isomorphism. In what context did this appear?

Comment: My task is to prove that some first order about graphs doesn't exists.  In solution (that I can't understand) is written: It is sufficient to show for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ two graphs $G_1,G_2$ such that $G_1$ fullfill first order sentence and $G_2$ doesn't meet this sentence and $G_1\equiv_m G_2$

Comment: For *elementary equivalece* : $G_1 \equiv G_2$ see e.g. [Marker](https://books.google.it/books?id=gkvogoiEnuYC&pg=PA13), page 13.

Comment: For $A \equiv_n B$, see [Marker](https://books.google.it/books?id=gkvogoiEnuYC&pg=PA54), page 54.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quantifier depth* is a measure on first order sentences (in a language with quantifiers) that, roughly speaking, measures how many levels of nested quantifiers ($\forall$ and $\exists$) are present in the sentence.

For example, if $\phi$ is a quantifier-free formula, then
$$
\forall x \exists y \forall z \phi
$$
has quantifier depth $3$.  I imagine that the full definition is given in your notes somewhere.

Given a first order theory$\newcommand{\T}{\mathbb T}$ $\T$, we say that two $\T$-strutures $A$ and $B$ are *elementarily equivalent*, and write $A\equiv B$, if $A$ and $B$ satisfy exactly the same sentences in $\T$.

As a weakening of this, for $n\in\mathbb N$ we write $A\equiv_n B$ if $A$ and $B$ satisfy exactly the same sentences *as long as those sentences have quantifier depth at most $n$*.

There might be some sentence $s$ of quantifier depth $n+1$ such that $A$ satisfies $s$ but $B$ doesn't.

Why is this a useful definition?  Well, suppose that you have some property $P$ of graphs and suppose that $P$ were given by some formula $s$ in the first-order theory of graphs.  Let $m$ be the quantifier depth of $s$: then we know that if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are graphs such that $G_1\equiv_m G_2$, then $G_1$ satisfies property $P$ if and only if $G_2$ satisfies property $P$ (since, by the definition of $\equiv_m$, we know that $G_1$ satisfies $s$ if and only if $G_2$ satisfies $s$).

Now suppose that we are trying to show that the property $P$ is *not* given by any first-order sentence.  Then, by the discussion above, it suffices to show that for any $n$ there exist graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that $G_1\equiv_nG_2$ but that $G_1$ satisfies property $P$ and $G_2$ does not.

---

**Update (addressing the OP's questions):** If $G_1,G_2$ are two *finite* graphs, then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are elementarily equivalent (in the first-order theory of graphs) if and only if they are isomorphic.  To see this, let $G=(\{v_1,\dots,v_j\},E(G))$ be a finite graph: then a graph $H$ satisfies the following formula:

$$
(\exists v_1\dots v_n).\bigwedge_{1\le i<j\le n}(v_i\ne v_j) \wedge (\forall v.(v=v_1)\vee\dots\vee (v=v_n))\wedge\bigwedge_{\{v_i,v_j\}\in E(G)}v_i\sim v_j\wedge\bigwedge_{\{v_i,v_j\}\not\in E(G)}\neg(v_i\sim v_j)
$$

This formula asserts the existence of $n$ distinct vertices, asserts that these are the only vertices in the graph and further asserts that the edge relations between these vertices are precisely those given by the graph $G$.  It is not too difficult to see that the graphs satisfying the sentence above are precisely the graphs that are isomorphic to $G$.

(**Note:** it is essential that the graph $G$ is finite; indeed, two infinite graphs may be elementarily equivalent but non-isomorphic.)

The quantifier depth of the above sentence is $n+1$, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph $G$.

Now consider the graphs you mentioned: the path of length $2^n$ and the path of length $2^n+1$.  These graphs are non-isomorphic and finite, so they are not elementarily equivalent.  However, if we want to use the recipe above to distinguish them, then it will take a sentence of quantifier depth $2^n+1$.

The statement that these graphs are $n$-equivalent means that we cannot distinguish between them using sentences of quantifier depth $n$ or less.  To see why that is, I recommend looking into Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games.

Comment: I don't undestand it indeed. My friend tell me that lecturer said that $G_1\equiv_n G_2$ when $G_1$ is path of  length $2^n$ and $G_2$ is path of length $2^{n}+1$. What does it mean ? Maybe that these two grahps are indistinguishable in first order logic, is it difficult to prove it ?